# Meteor: Update object1 if value equals X, else update object2

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm building a multiplayer game in Meteor.
Each `game` collection has a `player1` and `player2` which are objects with the user ID in it, and some game related data.

**Problem:**
I need to update the game related data on the `game`, but I don't know if the player is `player1` or `player2`.

The following would update `player1` but I need the function to be generic and only update the game related data on the right player object.

Have I made a mistake with the architecture, or am I missing a MongoDB function that can help me?

```js
Meteor.methods({
    changeHand: function(gameId, hand) {
        Games.update(gameId, {
            player1: {
                _id: Meteor.userId(),
                hand: hand
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a Mongo function that will allow this kind of conditional update. I recommend javascript side logic with a find then update:

```
Meteor.methods({
  changeHand: function(gameId, hand){
    var game = Games.findOne({_id: gameId});
    if(game.player1._id===Meteor.userId()){
      Games.update({_id: gameId}, {$set: {'player1.hand': hand}});
    }else{
      Games.update({_id: gameId}, {$set: {'player2.hand': hand}});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. It's not a problem that we first fetch the Game and then change it?

Comment: By the way, didn't know that you could parse strings instead of objects. Awesome! :)

Comment: You are making 2 calls instead of just 1, which has some cost. 
So long as you don't have to worry about the data changing (player1 and player2 id changing in this case) this *should* be fine. If that risk does exist, you'll have to look into making this an [atomic operation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/).